# Class extensions and typedef declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm doing an exercise where I have to create a class extension along with a custom method.
I've decided to use a typedef to allow for the use of parameters in my method.

Here's the header code that works:

```
#import "XYZPerson.h"

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, XYZNameDisplay) {
    XYZNameDisplayDefault,
    XYZNameDisplayReversed
};

@interface XYZPerson (XYZNameDisplay)

- (NSString *)xyz_nameDisplayWithParameter:(XYZNameDisplay)p;

@end
```

Two questions from here:

1. What is the scope of my typedef?
2. What are the consequences of declaring and instance variable outside of `@interface` or `@"implementation`?
3. Is a typedef equivalent to an instance variable?

Edit 21-nov-2014: I've tried putting the typedef between brackets in the `@"interface` but it returns an error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. The scope of the `typedef` is any file that includes/imports the header file containing the typedef.
2. A variable declared outside `@interface` or `@implementation` is not an instance variable. It will be a global of some sort (depending on where it is declared).
3. A typedef is not a variable of any kind. It's a data type.

FYI - none of your questions have anything to do with class extensions.